# How to give 64-bit iOS Framework Support for 32-bit Mac App [Project Catalyst - Xcode 11 Beta 2]

Tags: ios, xcode11, macos-catalina

As Apple said, "Bring iPad Apps to Mac", so I have an app which is perfectly running fine iPhone & iPad. I tried building for Mac and it gives me error for "ObjC linker for Classes" and which is obvious because `iOS` doesn't support "32-bit architecture", whereas Mac still does't it!

So, can anyone say how to solve this problem?

Comment: 32-bit support is on the way out on macOS, Apple might already have stopped accepting 32-bit apps in the Mac App Store. Just build 64-bit only on macOS – do that in the project settings. HTH

Comment: @CRD Tried still no luck, using this architecture pls check and let me know if I am making some mistakes. https://prnt.sc/o4701b

Comment: With only "ObjC linker for Classes" to go on it will be hard for anyone to help you further. *Something* in your project is either requesting a 32-bit build, trying to use 32-bit (say you're using an external framework which is 32-bit only), etc. You just have to work through the build logs and project settings to find out what it is.

You could also ask a new one providing more details – full error messages, what you've tried etc., and someone might figure it.

Finally remember you using beta software here, which increases the chance you may have hit a bug and should report it if so.